# maximum parallel threads foreach loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, asynchronous, parallel.foreach

How to add maximum parallel threads for this loop :

```
Parallel.ForEach(DataRow drValue in dtValues.Rows)
{
}
```

This is not working :

```
Parallel.ForEach(DataRow drValue in dtValues.Rows, new ParallelOptions {MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4})
{
}
```

Comment: Not working? Can you be more precise - what behaviour do you see instead?

Comment: At DataRow...it is showing ClassName is not valid at this point..

Comment: `Parallel.ForEach()` is not built-in into the language, it's a normal method. So you can't use the syntax for `foreach` in it.

Answer (score 2):

Try using lambda:

```
Parallel.ForEach(dtValues.Rows.AsEnumerable(), new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4 }, drValue =>
{
    //logic goes here
});
```

and to have this method you have to include `System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll` in your project. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatableextensions.asenumerable.aspx).

Comment: On ForEach it is showing - The type argument can not be inferred from the usage...Dont we need to define `drValue` here?

Comment: @Akon see my edit, forgot that data table rows have to be `enumarable`

Comment: Now - Can not resolve ForEach (DataRowColloection, threading option, lambda expression)

Comment: @Akon sorry, my first edit was wrong, corrected it now.You were faster than I with my correction ;)

Comment: @Akon once again, fixed for last time hopefully